# Filter verbose Azure ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

Exported Azure ARM template contains a lot's of useless information, let's say snapshots. I would like export actual resource definitions only.

Is it possible to filter unnecessary items out? I would like to convert this template to Bicep (to deploy all the resources into an another subscription) and now I have to clear manually all the unused items from the exported ARM template.

Comment: Exporting an ARM template from the resource group or resource will give you a template which is a snapshot of the current properties so it includes all the properties which was changed after the initial deployment. You can also try exporting templates from the deployment history too which will give you an option to export you very initial version without the changes you made after each deployment (if that's what you are looking for). This link shows how it's done https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/export-template-portal#export-template-after-deployment

Comment: Thank you @GopakumarR. It would be nice to export the final version of the resource group without frost, but then I have to wait for this feature.

Comment: I understand what you mean, we maintain all our resources in source control as ARM templates and use CICD to deploy, when ever there is a changes, so we always have our latest version of ARM templates with us and use it build up a new environment when a need comes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you [Gopa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13730676/gopa). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

Exporting an ARM template from the resource group or resource will give you a template that is a **snapshot** of the current properties so it includes all the properties which were changed after the initial deployment.

You can also try exporting templates from the **deployment history** too which will give you an option to export your initial version without the changes you made after each deployment.

You can maintain all resources in source control as ARM templates and use **CI/CD** to deploy, whenever there is a change, so you can have our latest version of ARM templates and use it to build up a new environment when a need comes.

You can export the template that was used to deploy existing resources. The template you get is exactly the one that was used for deployment.

**[Export template after deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/export-template-portal#export-template-after-deployment)**

1. Select the resource group you want to export.
2. Select the link under Deployments.
   [image]
3. Select one of the deployments from the deployment history.
   [image]
4. Select Template. The template used for this deployment is displayed, and is available for download.
   [image]

Comment: This is not the exact answer for my question but the sad - actual - truth.